# Не добавляет запись в MySQL из PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Код PHP выводит информацию из БД правильно, но не может записать в неё. Никаких ошибок не выводит при добавлении записи, возвращает эту же страницу с тем же содержимым. Основной файл:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/stye.css">
  <title>Prods</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Prods</h1>
    <form action="/prods.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Название продукта">
      <input type="date" name="data" placeholder="Дата привоза продукта">
      <input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Количество товара">
      <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Сумма">
      <button type="submit" name="sendProd">Сохранить</button>
    </form>


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
if($title == '') {
    echo 'Введите название продукта';
    exit();
}
$data = $_POST['data'];
if($data == '') {
    echo 'Выберите дату';
    exit();
}
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
if($quantity == '') {
    echo 'Введите количество товара';
    exit();
}
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
if($amount == '') {
    echo 'Введите сумму';
    exit();
}

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qwe';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO prod(title) VALUES(:title)';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['title' =>$title ,]);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO prod(data) VALUES(:data)';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['data' =>$data ,]);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO prod(quantity) VALUES(:quantity)';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['quantity' =>$quantity ,]);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO prod(amount) VALUES(:amount)';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['amount' =>$amount ,]);    

header('Location: /personal_arena.php');
```

?>

Comment: А зачем ты вставляешь 4 сроки?

Comment: я так пробовал, так как не выводит запись думал ошибка и на 4 строки добавил INSERT INTO `prod` (`id`, `title`, `data`, `quantity`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL, :title, :data, :quantity, :amount);

Comment: "пробовать" никогда не надо. Надо делать только один вариант - правильный, а если не работает то не "пробовать", а разбираться, почему не работает. Читай ответ прикремленный сверху